# Python request - the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Tags: python, post, request, multipart

(I'm still new to API endpoints in python so apologies if I am missing an easy answer here, but I haven't been able to find it.)

I'm trying to make a post request to an endpoint that uses a multipart/form-data request, where you include a file to be uploaded.

I'm attempting to post the following:

```
import requests

url = &&&
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 
           'Authorization': authtoken, 
           'x-api-key': x_api_key, 
           'Accept': 'application/vnd.###.v1+json'}
files = {'file': ('filename.csv', open('filename.csv', 'rb'),'text/csv')}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
r.text
```

(Note that "&&&" and "###" represent confidential links.)

I get this error:

"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found","path":"&&&"

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Do I need to set a multipart boundary? How can I do so? If it seems like you need more info to answer this question, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You need `requests-toolbelt` multipart data support: https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html

Comment: I have on occasion had need of this before, especialy when uploading a large file; you can check my specific use case here: https://github.com/rnag/wystia/blob/main/wystia/api_upload.py#L68-L72

Comment: @rv.kvetch Getting an error regarding the utils package: NameError: name 'retry_on_connection_error' is not defined. Can you confirm how to install utils to use this function?

Comment: You can feel free to ignore that function call 'retry_on_connection_error' and just remove it if needed. It's just a utility decorator I created to retry on `BrokenPipeError`s that I used to get in my Python script sometimes. If curious I do define it [here](https://github.com/rnag/wystia/blob/main/wystia/utils/decorators.py#L16) in the utils.py module.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set Content-Type in headers, requests will set it correctly for you.

Comment: this answer saved my hours. if you are using a javascript FormData DO NOT SET requestHeader('Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")